# Does Flash have properties like C#?

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript-3

Does flash have properties like C#? Or do I have to create getters and setters like java?

I.E. Can I do this in flash:

```
public int UserID {get; private set}
```

Comment: note that setter and getter in flash should be of same access level (you can't have private setter and a public getter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create getters and setters. For example,

```
public function set myValue (value:Number):void
{ 
            _myValue = value;
}

public function get myValue ():Number
{
           return _myValue ;
}

private var _myValue : Number;
```

For a read-only property provide only a getter.

Comment: Both setter and getter should have same access modifier (public/private/protected). You can't have a private setter and a public getter.